# How to get a Docusign API access token using JWT with the SDK in PHP?

Tags: docusignapi

So, I think I already set up everything in my account, because I already have my user ID, client ID and the private key. According to [documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/) I should be able to import `ApiClient.php` and call `requestJWTUserToken` to get an Access Token. This is how it looks now

```
$config = new Configuration();
$apiClient = new ApiClient($config);

$client_id = config('docusign.integration_key');
$user_id = config('docusign.user_id');
$rsa_private_key = openssl_pkey_get_private("file://docusign.pem");

$apiClient->requestJWTUserToken($client_id, $user_id, $rsa_private_key);
```

However, I'm getting an error message

```
Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [400] with response Body:  O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:5:"error";s:13:"invalid_grant";s:17:"error_description";s:16:"issuer_not_found";}

  at vendor/docusign/esign-client/src/Client/ApiClient.php:344
    340|             if(is_object($serializedData)){
    341|                 $serializedData = serialize($serializedData);
    342|             }
    343| 
  > 344|             throw new ApiException(
    345|                 "Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [".$response_info['http_code']."] with response Body:  $serializedData",
    346|                 $response_info['http_code'],
    347|                 $http_header,
    348|                 $data
```

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code if you're using Windows with Git Bash. I would download the [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/), run `composer install` and drop this file into the root folder.

Be sure to add the redirect URI of `https://httpbin.org/get` in your app in your DocuSign developer account. Also, paste your integration key and User ID in this file. In your `ds_config.php` file, set `quickstart` to `false`.

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

use DocuSign\eSign\Configuration;
use DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi;
use DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiClient;
use DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiException;
use DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi\ListStatusChangesOptions;


$rsaPrivateKey = file_get_contents("./private.key");
$integration_key = "";
$impersonatedUserId = "";
$scopes = "signature impersonation";


$config = new Configuration();
$apiClient = new ApiClient($config);
try {
    $apiClient->getOAuth()->setOAuthBasePath("account-d.docusign.com");
    $response = $apiClient->requestJWTUserToken($integration_key, $impersonatedUserId, $rsaPrivateKey, $scopes, 60);


} catch (\Throwable $th) {
    var_dump($th);
    // we found consent_required in the response body meaning first time consent is needed
    if (strpos($th->getMessage(), "consent_required") !== false) {
        $authorizationURL = 'https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?' . http_build_query([
            'scope'         => $scopes,
            'redirect_uri'  => 'https://httpbin.org/get',
            'client_id'     => $integration_key,
            'response_type' => 'code'
        ]);

        echo "It appears that you are using this integration key for the first time.  Please visit the following link to grant consent authorization.";
        echo "\n\n";
        echo $authorizationURL;
        exit();
    }
}

if (isset($response)) {
    $access_token = $response[0]['access_token'];
    // retrieve our API account Id
    $info = $apiClient->getUserInfo($access_token);
    $account_id = $info[0]["accounts"][0]["account_id"];

    // Instantiate the API client again with the default header set to the access token
    $config->setHost("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
    $config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $access_token);
    $apiClient = new ApiClient($config);


    $envelope_api = new EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
    $from_date = date("c", (time() - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60)));
    $options = new ListStatusChangesOptions();
    $options->setFromDate($from_date);
    try {
        $results = $envelope_api->listStatusChanges($account_id, $options);
        echo "results";
        echo "\n\n";
        echo stripslashes($results);
    } catch (ApiException $e) {
        var_dump($e);
        exit;
    }
}
```